# Kafka Consumer Paused Indefinitely

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactor-kafka

We are using the Kafka reactor for consuming and producing the Kafka message. We have noticed the consumer pause and resume during the message processing due to back pressure.
But unfortunately, the consumer is paused indefinitely after 3 or 4 resumes. The lag started to build up on the topics afterward. No exception logged.
The consumer code is below

**reactor-kafka (1.3.9)**

```
 KafkaReceiver<K,V> receiver = KafkaReceiver.create(consumerOptions);
        return Flux.defer(receiver::receive)
                .publishOn(defaultScheduler())
                .groupBy(m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
                .flatMap(
                        partitionFlux ->
                                partitionFlux.publishOn(defaultScheduler())
                                        .doOnNext(kvReceiverRecord -> kvReceiverRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge())
                                        .delayUntil(this::dispatch)
                                        .checkpoint("Dispatching the message to handler")
                )
                .retry()
                .repeat()
                .subscribe();
```

Can someone help me,

1. how to avoid the consumer going into a pause state indefinitely
2. In the Kafka reactor, on which condition the consumer would be paused and resumed

Comment: `Flux.groupBy` will hang if there are more groups open (not terminated) than the prefetch value (by default 256). Can you monitor how many `partitionFlux` instances are open when it hangs?

Comment: @PatrickHooijer Thank you for the prompt reply, Since the incident happened on production, we couldn't collect the number of groups. 
The default `max.poll.records` (500) is used with client configuration and only one partition was assigned to the instance during the incident time. so, it could be more than 256.

Comment: Then my best guess is that this is the problem. You can add the prefetch value as a second argument to groupBy: `.groupBy(m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition(), 1024)`. Or if you want to modify it for all prefetch operators in your project (not only groupBy), you can add the `reactor.bufferSize.small=1024` property.

Comment: Thank you, Let me try and update here

Comment: I found below two statements during the last pause `[reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.ConsumerEventLoop] DEBUG - Emitting 1 records, requested now 1
[reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.ConsumerEventLoop] DEBUG - Paused - back pressure`

Comment: Is your issue solved? I have a similar problem where the consumer is slow and reactor Kafka pauses and resumes partitions. But eventually partitions are just paused. Even calling resume function explicitly won’t help. I created a question here: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78110804/kafka-topic-partitions-are-paused-and-never-resumed-for-slow-consumer)

Comment: The cause of the problem was with groupby and flatmap. We couldn't find the better alternative for groupby.  the problem was resolved after removing the groupby